# Ошибка FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь добавить кнопку в ToolBar, в папке Меню создал файл со следующим содержимым

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:title="@string/action_settings"
app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
android:id="@+id/action_micro"
android:title="microphone"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_qr_code"
yourapp:showAsAction="always"
/>
```

При запуске, приложение вылетает с ошибкой  `FATAL EXCEPTION: main` если убрать строку ответственную за иконку `android:icon="@drawable/ic_qr_code"`  все работает.
Подскажите в чем может быть дело?

```
09-25 13:10:04.940 23220-23220/com.w4.w4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.w4.w4, PID: 23220
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070068
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1577)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:505)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:126)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:211)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:188)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:197)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:477)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1182)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:96)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:230)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:298)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1069)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1096)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:461)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:56)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5977)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:801)
```

Comment: Полный стек трейс ошибки приложите

Comment: Сделал.........

Comment: Попробуйте `clean` проекту сделать и/или `InstantRun` отключить, если он включен.

Comment: к сожалению не помогло